# use of redshift keys to make query efficient

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table with hundreds of millions of rows. My typical query looks like this...

```
select * from table where senddate > '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and senddate < '2015-08-01 00:00:00' and username = 'xyz'
```

I am not sure how sort and distribution keys work. I will like to know what should be the best option to make the query efficient.
I have around 3,000 unique usernames and senddate is a date within last 5 years.

I have one more question:

I am not using any compression for this table. Does that make the query slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Never use select * in a columnar DB, only pull the columns which are needed.
- If this is the only query you want to run, distribution keys dont matter. You can do a diststyle ALL but it will take n times the storage  where n is the number of nodes. That said, if you are going to join tables, distribute them on the joining keys
- You can have a sortkey on senddate, username to avoid reading all the records (similar to a table scan in row-stores)

Read through to have a basic understanding of these points 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-optimizing-query-performance.html

Comment: I have created a composite sort key on username and date column. I have also used appropriate column types. New table uses compression and It is now consuming only 43 GB compared to 263 GB disk space. Query is very fast. Thanks for tips. However using select col_names instead of * did not make much difference. Both were fast enough. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Good to know that it worked. Using only required columns is a best practice, the performance gains might not be visible if you are running only few queries, but in the long term this will improve the performance of the whole cluster.